# How would you use return multiple times within a function?

Tags: python, function, recursion, return, permutation

I am trying to write code, that given a list of characters, will generate all possible permutations of those characters. For example, ['a', 'b'] will return ['aa', 'ab', 'ba', bb']. I am doing this through a recursive algorithm with the following code.

```
def generate_perms(chars, str='', output=[]):
    
    if len(str) == len(chars):
        output.append(str)
        return output
    else:
        return generate_perms(chars, str+'a', output) + generate_perms(chars, str+'b', output)
```

The problem with this is that it only works when chars = [a, b] and if I wanted to pass different characters into chars I would have to manually change the last line, making this function rather useless.

A problematic solution that I thought of is as follows:

```
#replacing the last line with:

else:
    for i in chars:
        return generate_perms(chars, str+i, output)
```

The problem being that it gets to the first character, returns the first function fine, but then does not return the 'b' branch.

The final output returns: ['aa']

**How would I use return multiple times within a function?**

or otherwise solve the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [Python Program to print all permutations of a given string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/)

You are using static characters in line

```
return generate_perms(chars, str+'a', output) + generate_perms(chars, str+'b', output)
```

so it will only work for those characters in that order

in future just google stuff like this it's faster

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of achieving this result

1. using the built-in module itertools

```
    nums = list("ABC")
    permutations = list(itertools.permutations(nums))
     
   
    print([''.join(permutation) for permutation in permutations])
      # Output: ['ABC', 'ACB', 'BAC', 'BCA', 'CAB', 'CBA']
```

2. in case you want a recursive solution, you can make use of backtracking

We can do this by swapping each of the remaining characters in the string with its first character and generating all the permutations of the remaining characters using a recursive call. This is illustrated in the recursion tree shown below.
[image: recursion tree]

```
def swap(ch, i, j):
    temp = ch[i]
    ch[i] = ch[j]
    ch[j] = temp

def permutations(ch, curr_index=0):
 
    if curr_index == len(ch) - 1:
        print(''.join(ch))
 
    for i in range(curr_index, len(ch)):
        swap(ch, curr_index, i)
        permutations(ch, curr_index + 1)
        swap(ch, curr_index, i)
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    s = "ABC"
    #print(list(s))
    permutations(list(s))
```